# Wagtail - getting routablepageurl of page category in other page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have filter of category on mydomain.com/gallery/album/2017

```
class Gallery(RoutablePageMixin,Page):
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('short_description'),
        InlinePanel('image_gallery', label="image gallery"),
    ]

    def get_posts(self):
        return AlbumImageGallery.objects.all()

    @route(r'^albums/(?P<album>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_category(self, request, album, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_posts = self.get_posts().filter(album__slug=album)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Gallery, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['albums'] = Album.objects.all()
        context['album_image'] = AlbumImageGallery.objects.all()
        context['get_posts'] = self.get_posts
        context['gallery'] = self
        return context
```

In my HTML

```
<a href="{% routablepageurl gallery "post_by_category" each.slug %}"> {{each.album_name}}</a>
```

Now i want to get mydomain.com/gallery/album/2017 from my other page

```
class MymodelPage(Page):
    ...
    get_context():
        context['gallery_images'] = Image.objects.all()
        context['gallery'] = Gallery.objects.get()
```

MymodelPage.html

Error

```
NoReverseMatch at /media-corner/
Reverse for 'post_by_category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'albums/(?P<album>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

I want to get gallery url/slug on my Modal RoutablePageMixin
i tried to pass url page its gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `each.slug`. From the error message (
`with arguments '('',)'`), it appears that the `routablepageurl` tag has received an empty string as the `each.slug` argument. (This then fails to match your URL pattern, because it requires the `album` slug to be at least one character.)

Comment: Thanks but i can't get album it shows me None value when iterated is that because its ParentalManyToManyField ?

Comment: I have no idea - that's a completely different part of the code that you haven't shown me :-) If you aren't able to debug it yourself, I'd suggest opening that as a new question, since it's not really related to the behaviour of `routablepageurl`.